# rowindex on gridview control - VS 2008

Tags: asp.net

With a gridview control bound to a sql data source, i want to display a column named ID. The ID should display the row number for each row. How would I go about binding this to rowindex instead of the ID column from the database?

Answer (score 1):

For that I would use the ROW_NUMBER() function which is new in SQL Server 2005.
This function returns rownumber in the recordset that is being returned.
There is an [excellent post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/01/434314.aspx) by ScottGu.
HTH,
Valve.

Comment: Valve: Thanks for the info, Now If my data source changes to a objectdatasource bound to a List<T>, my dataset is transformed into List<T>. Can I still use ROW_NUMBER()